# eclipse android running AVD - panic: could not open

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have some problems when i try to run a AVD in "eclipse - android'. I know there are other questions on stackoverflow just like this, but i have tried different kind of solutions without any luck. 
I keep getting the error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test'
PANIC: Could not open: test
```

I have tried creating an environment variable (ANDROID_SDK_HOME) and set a "string substitution" (user.home)
And obviously, i have also tried reinstalling and so on.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding AVD issues, I always recommend giving a try to [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), it's by far the fastest android emulator I've ever worked with.

Comment: does it work with eclipse? as a plugin or something?

Comment: It's really a standalone application, but yes, includes a plugin to launch your app from eclipse.

Comment: hmm this is weird (didn't try genymotion yet).. I changed my workspace path to the same as the android sdk location. It seems to work now. But thanks for your help! I will try geny and ofc accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such a problem too. My solution is to create an environment variable (ANDROID_SDK_HOME) and set it as the user home directory (for my computer it's D:\Users\Bill).